# I can't show the values of my database in a graph using chartjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I'm trying to practice with chartjs, so I've downloaded some code from the Internet to adapt it to my needs.

I need to display the number of patients who were born in a specific month based on their dates of birth as well as their year of birth.

The issue is that I have searched for every way to display the information that I have in my database in the graph and I can't find the way, since the code of the graphs is in an external javascript file.

I have been trying to solve this for a long time, please, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me

**table Pacients**

```
CREATE TABLE `pacients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `document_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `document_numb` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `pregncy` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_birth` date NOT NULL
  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;



INSERT INTO `pacients` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `document_name`, `document_numb`, `phone`, `sex`, `pregnancy`, `date_birth`) VALUES
(6, 'marta', 'mangue', 'DNI', 655, 222987665, 'Feminine', '', '2021-12-28', '', '', ''),
(7, 'Mayo', 'Esono', 'DNI', 5769, 551233234, 'Masculine', '', '2021-10-25', '', '', ''),
(40, 'Celso', 'NUESTRA', 'Passport', OF4334, 4343, 'Masculine', '', '2021-11-19', '', '', ''),
(41, 'Nathan', 'Narby Esimi', 'passport', P001111, 654890, 'Masculine', '', '2021-12-28', '', '', '');
```

**chart.js**

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctxGreen, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipGreen

    });
```

This is where I would like my information to appear

```
    var chart_labels = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
    var chart_data = [100, 70, 90, 70, 85, 60, 75, 60, 90, 80, 110, 100];


    var ctx = document.getElementById("chartBig1").getContext('2d');

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.1)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.0)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(119,52,169,0)'); //purple colors
    var config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: chart_labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: "My First dataset",
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: gradientStroke,
          borderColor: '#d346b1',
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderDash: [],
          borderDashOffset: 0.0,
          pointBackgroundColor: '#d346b1',
          pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#d346b1',
          pointBorderWidth: 20,
          pointHoverRadius: 4,
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
          pointRadius: 4,
          data: chart_data,
        }]
      },
      options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple
    };
    var myChartData = new Chart(ctx, config);
    $("#polio").click(function() {
      var data = myChartData.config.data;
      data.datasets[0].data = chart_data;
      data.labels = chart_labels;
      myChartData.update();
    });
    $("#sarampion").click(function() {
      var chart_data = [80, 120, 105, 110, 95, 105, 90, 100, 80, 95, 70, 120];
      var data = myChartData.config.data;
      data.datasets[0].data = chart_data;
      data.labels = chart_labels;
      myChartData.update();
    });

    $("#paludismo").click(function() {
      var chart_data = [60, 80, 65, 130, 80, 105, 90, 130, 70, 115, 60, 130];
      var data = myChartData.config.data;
      data.datasets[0].data = chart_data;
      data.labels = chart_labels;
      myChartData.update();
    });


    var ctx = document.getElementById("CountryChart").getContext("2d");

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(29,140,248,0.2)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(29,140,248,0.0)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(29,140,248,0)'); //blue colors
```

**index.php** this is the php file where the graph is displayed

```
<?php include("plantillas/header.php"); ?>


<section class="panelControl">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="plantillas/header.php"></a>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 titulo-panel">
                <h2 class="card-title">Administration panel</h2>
                <p>Check patient statistics</p>

<div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card  custom-card">
                <div class="card-header ">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                        <h5 class="card-category">Pacients</h5>
                        <h2 class="card-title">Statistics of registered patients</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                            
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle float-right" data-toggle="buttons">
                           
                        
                        <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-simple active" id="Poliomyelitis">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" checked>
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block">Poliomyelitis</span>
                            <span class="d-block d-sm-none">
                            <i class="tim-icons icon-single-02"></i>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-simple" id="Measles">
                            <input type="radio" class="d-none d-sm-none" name="options">
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block">Measles</span>
                            <span class="d-block d-sm-none">
                            <i class="tim-icons icon-gift-2"></i>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-simple" id="Malaria">
                            <input type="radio" class="d-none" name="options">
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block">Malaria</span>
                            <span class="d-block d-sm-none">
                            <i class="tim-icons icon-tap-02"></i>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="chart-area">
                    <canvas id="chartBig1"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

I have searched for solutions by looking at various tutorials but so far I have not found any that help me

Comment: Where's the code that selects data from the database? Is this a JS problem, a  PHP problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your js chart to import the data from the database. In that case, you should look into fetch() method.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials out there that describe how to retrieve data from mysql via php and send it to the client.

Comment: You could, for example, use an AJAX request to fetch the chart data from the server.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).